# moving divs with JAVASCRIPT like CSS3 with no lags

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my javascript code ,I m moving a div in a page with javascript (NOT CSS3) and it contains some lags! what should I do to release from this lag? (with CSS3 I will have no lags but i wonna use JAVASCRIPT ) :| THank u in advance.

my JAVASCRIPT:

```
var margin_left_ltr = -1366;
var margin_left_rtl = 1366;

var margin_left_controler = 2.75;
function go_next(){
    var coming = setInterval(function come(){
        var firstDiv = document.getElementById('first_ltr');
        var thirdDiv = document.getElementById('third_ltr');
        var secondDiv = document.getElementById('second_rtl');

        firstDiv.style.marginLeft = margin_left_ltr + margin_left_controler + 'px';
        thirdDiv.style.marginLeft = margin_left_ltr + margin_left_controler + 'px';
        secondDiv.style.marginLeft = margin_left_rtl + (-margin_left_controler) + 'px';

        if((parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(firstDiv).marginLeft)) >= 0){
            clearInterval(coming);  
        }   
        margin_left_controler += 2.80;
    },10)

}
```

my HTML :

```
<div class="click" onClick="go_next();">
        click here!   
</div>

<div id="container_about_us">

    <div id="first_ltr">

        <div id="exit" onClick="go_out();">
            X
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="second_rtl">

    </div>

    <div id="third_ltr">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you upload it to edit jsfiddle so we can know the cause of lags

Comment: You could cache firstDiv, thirdDiv, secondDiv out of the go_next() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with jQuery. To move the div by increasing it's margin use :

```
function go_next(){
    var firstDiv=$('#first_ltr'),
        secondDiv=$('#second_ltr'),
        thirdDiv=$('#third_ltr');

    //Rest of your code.To move with margins :

    firstDiv.animate({"margin-left":"+= 2.75px"},1000);
    secondDiv.animate({"margin-left":"+= 2.75px"},1000);
    thirdDiv.animate({"margin-left":"+= 2.75px"},1000);
}
```

Comment: my code works but , when my divs are moving, i have some lag in their move.i wonna move divs without lag :|

Comment: What kind of lag are you getting?

Comment: I do the same code with CSS and there were no lag! in CSS both CPU and GPU are using , but in this code of JAVASCRIPT only CPU is using ,because of that, my div  have a little lag while moving , i dont know how to use both CPU and GPU :|

Comment: One thing I observed now is that you have used `setInterval`. Do read about `requestAnimationFrame`. And by Laggy do you mean that you want to be able to see the animation?

Comment: yes exactly I wonna see animation , I m trying requestAnimationFrame then I will let u know the result . thank u. :)

Comment: I just edited the answer. It uses jQuery's animate function which animates it by one second. If you want the time interval to be more just change the second parameter. The time is in mili-seconds. Please upvote and select If I  helped you